# Add div wrapper around elements inside dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to wrap elements inside a `dropdown-menu` with a div.

The structure is like below:

```html
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Category</a>
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of category</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of category</a>
</div>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Brands</a>
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```html
<!-- Start of first dropdown menu -->
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
<div class="add-wrapper-here">
<!-- Start of second dropdown menu -->
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Category</a>
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of category</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of category</a>
</div>
<!-- End of second dropdown menu -->
</div>

<div class="add-wrapper-here">
<!-- Start of second dropdown menu -->
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Brands</a>
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
</div>
<!-- End of second dropdown menu -->
</div>

</div>
<!-- End of first dropdown menu -->
```

To clarify:
I want to add a div wrapper around the elements inside the first dropdown-menu:

START FIRST DROPDOWN MENU
div dropdown-menu

**START DIV WRAPPER**
a href element
second dropdown-menu
**END DIV WRAPPER**

END FIRST DROPDOWN MENU

All help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Would be nice if you presented a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Kooilnc,

I have tried to present it in the second code snippet.

Comment: "<div class="add-wrapper-here">"

Comment: Hi, so you need to do this using jquery?

Comment: Hi @Swati 

Yes that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) , [addBack()](https://api.jquery.com/addback/) and [wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to achieve this .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('a.dropdown-item').next("div").each(function() {
  //get previous element i.e : `a` tag then use addback as well inside divs
  $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='add-wrapper' />");
});
```

```css
.add-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Category</a>
  <div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of category</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of category</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Brands</a>
  <div class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="">Name of brand</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes!! Perfect, this was exactly what i was looking for :)